# Permutation and order statistic

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, order-statistics, permutation

Let $X_1,…,X_n$ be i.i.d. random variables. Are these two equalities correct?

$P[X_{(2)}<x_2,…,X_{(n)}<x_n| X_{(1)}=x_1]=\\
=n!P[X_{2}<x_2,…,X_{n}<x_n| X_{1}=x_1]=\\
=n! P[X_{2}<x_2]…P[X_{n}<x_n]$

And if not, why? I am a bit confused as I don’t know if the permutations are also considering the fact that the minimum $X_{(1)}$ could be any of the $n$ variables.

Thank you.

Comment: I should add that $x_1<x_2<…<x_n$ in the first equality like it is usually done with order statistics?

Comment: You're missing some additional conditions. Take $n=2$ for simplicity, $X_{1,2}$ as standard normal. Say your minimum is 0. But now suppose $x_2 =0$. $P(X_{(2)} < 0 | X_{(1)}=0) = 0$ but $P(X_{2} < 0 | X_{(1)}=0) = 0.5$ regardless of the factorial term.

Comment: You can trivially choose $x_2$ only a "smidge" (an epsilon) above $x_1$ and see my counterexample holds.

Comment: You are right, thank you. Does it hold if the random variables are Exp(1)? I mean, there could be particular cases where it holds or not?

Comment: This is a question about relationships among *events,* so it will suffice to contemplate the case where all the variables have a uniform$[0,1]$ distribution, if you even need to compute probabilities at all.  For the case $n=2$ you can draw useful diagrams of these events in the plane (and you could try some space diagrams for $n=3$ if you're good at that).